# Using Symfony forms, is there a way to persist unmapped field values to the database and retrieve them later to rebuild the form?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

Using Symfony's form component, I have a "Report Settings" form with about 35 options and a few embedded forms.  Is there a way to gather the selected options, persist them to a database, and then at a later date use those persisted options to re-build the form reflecting the previously chosen options without creating a dedicated entity for either the form itself or for the embedded forms?

I know I can serialize the array and store it in a single field - this is perfect, but I cannot figure out how to retrieve that field and re-apply it to the form so a user can change their report settings.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a nullable field to the user entity. Then put your serialize/deserialize logic in the getter/setter for the field. So you end up with *something* like this to use it:

```
$user->setReportSettings($form->getData());

$form->setData($user->getReportSettings());
```

Comment: Thanks - I wound up with a variation of that and I had tried something similar earlier but getData() was returning all the fields _plus_ the form metadata and serialize was complaining about serializing closures.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally ended up with.

When I add a new report that needs settings, I create a new unmapped form and embed it in MasterReportSettingsType.  This handles new/existing settings and retrieving existing settings for modification.

Just using getData() on the parent form or even iterating over the embedded forms and using getData() returns the fields *and* the form metadata which was undesirable.  With this I only get the field and its value and Doctrine handles serialization/deserialization.

```
    public function reportSettingsAction(
        Request $request
    )
    {
        $account = $this->getUser()->getAccount();
        $form    = $this->createForm(MasterReportSettingsType::class);
        $rs      = $this->rsRepository->getReportSettingsForAccount($account);

        if (null !== $rs) {
            // Apply existing report settings to form
            foreach ($rs->getSettings() as $formKey => $fields) {
                foreach ($fields as $fieldKey => $fieldValue) {
                    if (($form->has($formKey)) && ($form->get($formKey)->has($fieldKey))) {
                        $form->get($formKey)
                             ->get($fieldKey)
                             ->setData($fieldValue)
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            // Retrieve the embedded forms, their fields, and the field values
            foreach ($form->all() as $key => $subform) {
                foreach ($subform->all() as $fieldKey => $fieldValue) {
                    $settings[$key][$fieldKey] = $fieldValue->getData();
                }
            }

            if (null === $rs) {
                // If there were no existing report settings
                $rs = new ReportSettings();
            }

            $rs->setAccount($account);
            $rs->setSettings($settings);
            $this->em->persist($rs);
            $this->em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Settings saved');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('report-settings');
        }

        return $this->render('report/report_settings.html.twig', $form->createView());
    }
```